# How can I pass a Array via JQuery Get without using post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

How can I pass a Array via JQuery Get without using post

my jquery code is

```
$('[name="SelectHighlights"]:checked').each(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    var high = {
        AccountName: row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text(),
        Highcomments: row.find('td:nth-child(3) > input').val()
    };
    HighlightsArea.push(high);
});

var HL=HighlightsArea.length;
alert(''+HL);
if(HL>0)
{
    GetJson(
        GetRootPath() + '/WeeklySales/AjaxUpdateHighComments', //url
        //JSON.stringify(HighlightsArea), //Data: 
        //HighlightsArea,
        //{high: HighlightsArea},
        {array: HighlightsArea.join(",")},
        SaveChanges //callBack
    );

}
```

Function for GetJSon:

```
function GetJson(url, data, onSuccess) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: GenericErrorHandler,
        traditional: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
    });
}
```

code in my controller :

I want to pass that array into this controller only but i should not use HTTpPost

```
public ActionResult AjaxUpdateHighComments(List<Highlights> Highlights, WeeklySalesModel weeklysales){}
```

Please help me 
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you use a post?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you must convert to string first your JSON Array on Passing data.

> Client-side

```
function GetJson(url, data, onSuccess) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data), // converted to string
        success: onSuccess,
        error: GenericErrorHandler,
        traditional: true,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
    });
}
```

Try this code to your

> Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AjaxUpdateHighComments(string highlights)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Highlights> listHighlights = jss.Deserialize<List<Highlights>>(highlights);

 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit ambiguous in your question but i'll give it a go, assuming you mean you want to prevent posting to the Action?

You can add a attribute on the action to prevent this [MSDN HttpGetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpgetattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

for example

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AjaxUpdateHighComments(List<Highlights> Highlights, WeeklySalesModel weeklysales){}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, include the `$.postify` code from [**this article**](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/post-complex-javascript-objects-to-asp-net-mvc-controllers/).

Code for `$.postify`:

```
$.postify = function(value) {
    var result = {};

    var buildResult = function(object, prefix) {
        for (var key in object) {

            var postKey = isFinite(key)
                ? (prefix != "" ? prefix : "") + "[" + key + "]"
                : (prefix != "" ? prefix + "." : "") + key;

            switch (typeof (object[key])) {
                case "number": case "string": case "boolean":
                    result[postKey] = object[key];
                    break;

                case "object":
                    if (object[key].toUTCString)
                        result[postKey] = object[key].toUTCString().replace("UTC", "GMT");
                    else {
                        buildResult(object[key], postKey != "" ? postKey : key);
                    }
            }
        }
    };

    buildResult(value, "");

    return result;
};
```

I know the name sounds like it is for `POST` but it works for `GET` as well. Then change your code as below:

```
$('[name="SelectHighlights"]:checked').each(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    var high = {
        AccountName: row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text(),
        Highcomments: row.find('td:nth-child(3) > input').val()
    };
    HighlightsArea.push(high);
});

var HL = HighlightsArea.length;
alert('' + HL);
if (HL > 0) {    
    //Property names should match the parameters' name given in the controller method
    var objRequest = {
        Highlights: HighlightsArea,
        weeklysales: {/* weekly sales object goes here */}
    };    
    GetJson(
    GetRootPath() + '/WeeklySales/AjaxUpdateHighComments',
    $.postify(objRequest), // $.postify is the key
    SaveChanges //callBack
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much can you please let me know whther i need to add any plugin fir this.

Comment: Other than `jQuery` (which you already have), you just need the `$.postify` code given in the article/link i've provided. For your convenience i've updated my answer with the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working very very fine but only thing is in the code i gave above Highcomments is value from text box ,i am not getting that value in controller,it is showing null can you please help me

Comment: What about `AccountName`? Are you getting the value/text for that in the controller?

Comment: In that case, this line `row.find('td:nth-child(3) > input').val()` is not working as intended. Can you post a piece/snippet of the html output?

Comment: but for this i kept an alert and checked ,i am getting a value in jquery

Comment: Can you post your `script` & `html` in jsfiddle?